# fullPage js scrollable div doesn't function with anchors

Tags: jquery, anchor, fullpage.js

I'm developing a page where i use the fullPage.js plugin by Alvarotrigo. I use the built in option for anchor links.

**The problem**

When i choose one of the last pages in the menu and scrolls up to a previous one, it cuts the section. I'm using the options "scrollOverflow" and "scrollBar" for the sections that are heigher than 100vh.

See the live example here: [link](http://weshape.dk/hypr4/)

Try to choose the menu item "Hvem er vi" in the menu, and scroll all the way up and down again to see the problem, if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be initializing the fullPage.js library anywhere in your code.
Therefore you are not actually using fullPgage.js. Just loading it without using it.

Also:

> I'm using the options "scrollOverflow" and "scrollBar" for the sections that are heigher than 100vh.

This options shouldn't be used together and will lead to bugs in certain browsers.